# Error on file size when uploading the image

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to upload a file using the following script. The script uploads the file via browse button, but when I click on the upload button, it gives an error //Error on file size.

FYI - manually upload for the same file is successful

My script:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='fileUploadInput']/div/div[2]/input[2]")).sendKeys(file_upload);
driver.findElement(By.id("btnCreativeHostingFileUpload")).click();
```

HTML:

```
<tr id="fileOas" style="display: table-row;">
<td align="left" style="height:25px;">File Name</td>                                                                            
<td nowrap="" align="left" style="height:40px;">
<input type="hidden" style="width:250px" name="uploadFileName" id="videoUploadFileName" value="tag.png">
<div onclick="setActiveUploadForUploadAll();" style="height:40px;">
<!-- <iframe id="sUploadAll" name="sUploadAll" onmouseover="setActiveUpload('sUploadAll');" -->
<iframe width="470" height="40" frameborder="no" allowtransparency="true" scrolling="no" src="/richmedia/oas/FileUpload.do?nextAction=/oas/adwizard.banner.update.do&amp;currentPage=/oas/adwizard.creative.index.do&amp;fileCategory=image&amp;fieldName=videoUploadFileName&amp;previousFile=" onmouseover="prepareActiveUpload('sUploadAll');" name="sUploadAll" id="sUploadAll">
</iframe>
<input type="hidden" name="videoUploadFileNameFullUrl" id="videoUploadFileNameFullUrl" value="tag.png">
 <input type="hidden" name="videoUploadFileDownloadUrl" id="videoUploadFileDownloadUrl">
<input type="hidden" value="" id="currentSelectFileId">
<input type="hidden" value="" id="currentSelectFileType">
 <input type="hidden" name="uploadFileNameFullUrl" id="uploadFileNameFullUrl" value="tag.png">
<input type="hidden" name="dimensionWidth" id="dimensionWidth">
 <input type="hidden" name="dimensionHeight" id="dimensionHeight">
</div>
</td>                                                                           
</tr>


<div>
    <div class="input_div">
        <input type="text" readonly="readonly" class="file_input_textbox" id="fileName">
    </div>
    <div class="file_input_div">
        <input type="button" value="Browse" class="file_input_button">
        <input type="file" style="width:100px;" onchange="javascript: document.getElementById('fileName').value = this.value" value="" size="25" name="theFile">
    </div>
    <div class="upload_btn_div">
        <button onclick="showProgressAndUpload(this.form);" name="btnCreativeHostingFileUpload" id="btnCreativeHostingFileUpload" type="button" style="margin-left: 10px" class="btn btn_gray"><div><p>Upload</p></div></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Same file works manually?

Comment: yes, it does. Tried few times

Comment: Can you provide the html? And, stacktrace if possible

Comment: It is not failing the test, so won't be able to provide you any stacktrace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are using wrong selector

Try this cssSelector

```
[type='file']
```

Or, that input tag has the name as well. So you can use `theFile` as `By.name`

So, far in that's the only file input tag I am seeing in the html you have provided

You can also do this with JavaScript executor in case the above does not work

```
String filePath = "the filepath with extension";
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("document.getElementById('fileName').setAttribute('value', '"+filePath+"');");
driver.findElement(By.id("btnCreativeHostingFileUpload")).click();
```

Comment: is this correct?..... driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[type='file']")).sendKeys(file_upload);, because its still giving me the same error

Comment: Can you share the *file_upload* string?

Comment: this is how it is in the configuration file         #FILE UPLOAD
ASSET = /Assets/image.jpg, and this is how it is in the class      String file_upload = System.getProperty("user.dir") + PropertyLoader.loadProperty("ASSET");

Comment: I would try using direct filepath just to see if it works first

Comment: you are not going to believe it...so, i put .png and it went thru, having issues with jpg(with scripts only), because manually it uploads jpg....strange!!!!

Comment: You can also write the JavaScript to directly set the filepath value instead. do not if it is firing the `onchange` evvent correctly. That can be an issue

Comment: i am clueless with js, is it possible you can provide me with the sample code?

Comment: Provided code. Make sure you perform the click to upload the file.

Comment: You are just unstoppable, dude!